# converter inteiro pra String em java

Tags: java, string, int, parse

Como faço para converter o tipo Inteiro para String em Java?

A variável `matricula` está declarada como inteiro, porém para mostrar ela na tela ele pede para converter ela em String.

```
txtmatricula.setText(txtmat.getMatricula()));
```

Comment: `Integer.toString(txtmat.getMatricula());`

Comment: @AugustoVasques obrigado

Comment: `txtmat.getMatricula() + "";`

Answer (score 3):

**Use String.valueOf()**

```
String matriculaString = String.valueOf(txtmat.getMatricula())
txtmatricula.setText(matriculaString);
```

**Vantagens**

- Serve também para os tipos: Double, Float ou Long;
- Tem o propósito de ser usado em conversões, por isso muitas classes possuem esse metódo, como: String, Integer, Double, Bigdecimal, etc.
- No caso do Integer, o `valueOf()` cacheia números frenquentemente usado de -127 ao 128;
- Delega a conversão da String para o respectivo metódo da classe, no caso do Integer, delegaria para `Integer.toString()`, o que deixa a representação de número em String, consistente;

Fonte em inglês: https://www.java67.com/2012/10/best-way-to-convert-numbers-to-string-in-java-example.html